# How to get the pixel points of the contours?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, canny-operator

How can I find the pixel points in the contour? Suppose I have an Image which have 5 contours after doing `findContours`, I know we can drar the contours with `drawContour` function, but I need to know the pixel points which forms the contour.

For example:

```
    cv::medianBlur(img1,img1,7);
    Canny(src1,img1,250,350,3);
    imshow("abc",img1);

    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(img1, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++){         
    cv::drawContours(src2,contours,i,Scalar(255,100,200),2);
}
```

I did this and got this image  now I want to now the pixel points forming the contour, for example `(x1,Y1)`,`(x2,y2)`,`...` how do I get those information? [image: here],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contour is a 2D `vector` of `Point`. So, to access each point you can use 2 `for` loops (The code displays  the x-y co-ordinates of each point with the contour IDs), as show below -

```
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size; i++)
    for(int j = 0; i < contours.size; j++)
        cout << "ID = " << i << "( " << contours[i][j].x 
            << " , " << contours[i][j].y << " )"<< endl;
```

You can actually reduce the number of points in the contour by using the `approxPolyDP` to better visualize the data. Check the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp).

Answer (score 2):

As you write yourself in the code, the variable `contours` is a `vector< vector<Point> >` : vector of vector of points. Meaning, every contour is a vector of points.

This means, `contours[0]` would give you one vector of points (corresponding to the 0th contour), `contours[1]` would give you another list of points, and so on.